# XSD empty value for Integer datatype

Tags: types, xsd, integer

I have below mentioned XSD & in some scenarios user may not send any value for CarLoan(integer datatype). How do i allow XSD for empty integer value using expressions`

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Credit">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CarLoan">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="HousingLoan">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add "nillable" attribute and set it to "true" in your "CarLoan" element definition. If you are performing XML Schema validation on the XML instance you have to include "xsi:nil='true'" attribute as well in CarLoan element.

```
 <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CarLoan" nillable="true">
```

and XML instance should be/would be like below:

```
<CarLoan test="xz" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Comment: I guess nillable="true" may not work as CarLoan node exists, it's just that there wouldn't be any value for the node

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Can you show how CarLoan will/should look?

Comment: Sorry was busy with other stuff & didn't get back to this. Some of sample xml's could be in this format

Comment: <credit>
<carloan test="Hello"/>
<housingloan>1220</housingloan>
</credit>